# Reliably benchmarking a Go function doing file I/O

Tags: go, benchmarking

Initial benchmarking on my system indicates that this function is faster than os.ReadFile, but how can I benchmark it so that one can be confident that it is faster, for most OSes and filesystems? Either that, or show that is not faster at all? I am aware of the regular Go benchmarking tooling.

How can it be benchmarked so that the results can be trusted?

```golang
// ReadFileNoStat is similar to os.ReadFile, but does not call os.Stat to get the file size first.
// It also reads data into a 1024 bytes buffer.
func ReadFileNoStat(name string) ([]byte, error) {
    f, err := os.Open(name)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer f.Close()

    // Prepare the buffer
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0, 1024))

    _, err = buf.ReadFrom(f)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return buf.Bytes(), nil
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to do it without actually running on those OSes and filesystems? In which case you can't. Or is this more about "what pitfalls should I look for when bench-marking something"?

Comment: @RichardHuxton Both, but especially the latter. My question was a bit unclear. I guess there are no shortcuts.

Comment: You basically cannot. The first sort of ovbious thing is that the list of permutations of OSes supported by Go and filesystems and layers below them including the actual hardware storage device(s) would be bounded but still astonishingly big. So you would first need to come up with a set of permutations of those things you really care about. But then there's the question of FS performance depending on the current memory pressure on the system and activity not performed by your own process (whose activity is to be measured)…

Comment: …so, all-in-all, I would say: yes, we know for sure that not doing `stat(2)` on a file before reading it is probably going to speed up "slurps" (an act of opening a file, reading it completely in memory, then closing), but then should you really care? I mean, a use case which your approach can noticeably help should be so strange I cannot really envision it. It should be something like a web server (think of nginx) serving hordes of very small files to a massive set of clients quickly requesting them. But then maybe you should just precache them in memory.

Comment: @Alexander: As expected: `BenchmarkStat-12 2 690434654 ns/op 3535153732 B/op 15 allocs/op` and
 `BenchmarkNoStat-12 1 1691761099 ns/op 8589940360 B/op 55 allocs/op`

Comment: «…serving hordes of very small files…»–this also means that either all the clients would get those files streamed (using chunked encoding) as the server would not know the size of a file at the time of opening it or it would need to completely read each file to memory before serving it (after hitting the EOF the server knows the exact size).

Comment: The purpose is for my little editor [Orbiton](https://github.com/xyproto/orbiton), so my goal is to quickly slurp in small files (the size of a typical source code file or Markdow document).

Comment: OK, I see. My opinion is that it hardly helps (UX studies show that for a delay in some operation to be noticeable for a human it should be 30 ms or higher, and a `stat(2)` call on a typical desktop system adds, like, a dozen of ns) but… why not after all ;-)

Comment: …I mean, if we take, say, the venerable vim which is considered by many to be "blazing fast", on my system it opens, say, a random `.cpp` file "instantly". If I attach to it with `strace` before doing that, I can see what massive amount of work it performs to find and initialize file type and color plugins and so on. Actual reading of a file is dwarfed by those operations, and still the opening is instantaneous. What I'm leading to, is that some optimizations are fun to implement but their impact may really be miniscule. Say, sluggish UIs will affect the users much more than calling stat ;-)